# pass value from one page to another using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wish to call data from another page to my existing page through ajax. For this i have the following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".link").on("click", function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                console.log (id); // i am getting value in this id 
                $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "register.php",
                data :  id,
                cache : false,
                success : function(html)
                {
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }});
  });
});
</script>

<a class='link' data-id="$idd" >TEXT</a>
```

Till console.log (id) code is working, i am getting value inside id but i am not able to run the register.php page. I wish to carry the id to register.php page, run some code there and print its result under #msg, can anyone please tell how i can correct my ajax code

Comment: what is console.log(html) in your success callback ?

Comment: @Ludo i am not able to check console.log(html) as i am not getting any result

Comment: You can't do this like this. Passing value to Other page by ajax. how can you get it in other page?

Comment: you should do `data :  {id:id}`. then get id on `register.php` the variable `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Check your network requests tab. What is the returned response from the php script ?

Comment: change your ` url : "register.php",` with ` url : "register.php?userid=id",`. Also in your success function try alerting html like `alert(html);`

Comment: @roullie thanks your advice has helped in solving the issue, now i am getting the result

Answer (score 2):

You need to send data like data :  {id: id}

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".link").on("click", function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                console.log (id); // i am getting value in this id 
                $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "register.php",
                data :  {id: id},
                cache : false,
                success : function(html)
                { alert(html);
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }});
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data in `key/value` format. Now, you can check your data in `register.php` by printing `POST` array.

You can pass data in plain string like I shown in example also you can pass `JSON` object.

- "key1=value1&key2=value2...."
- { k1:v1, k2:v2,......}

  ```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".link").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).data("id");
          console.log (id); // i am getting value in this id 
          $.ajax({
              type : "post",
              url : "register.php",
              data :  "id="+id,  //you can pass value like this.
              cache : false,
              success : function(html) {
                  $('#msg').html(html);
              }
           });
      });
  });
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Check the values passed method

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".link").on("click", function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                //console.log (id); 
                $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "register.php",
                //data :  id,
                data:{'id':id},//values to be passed similarly
                cache : false,
                success : function(html)
                {
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }});
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you `$.ajax()` function like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'register.php',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('#msg').html(response);
    }
});
```

I hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url:'data.php',
              data: {
                  "id": 123,
                  "name": "abc",
                  "email": "abc@gmail.com"
              },
              success: function(ccc){

                  alert(ccc); 
                  $("#result").html(ccc);
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

data.php

```
echo $id = $_GET['id'];
echo $name = $_GET['name'];
echo $email = $_GET['email'];
```

Hope this will solve your issue.